# How to force abstract JSON data only from an API response?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, json-deserialization

## Description

I'm trying to make a request to an API via PHP cURL

```
$access_token = $tokens['access_token'];
$headers = array(
  "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token
  );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,env('USER_INFO'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$userInfo = curl_exec($ch);
$userInfo = json_decode($userInfo, true);

dd($userInfo);
```

I kept getting this back

`{"sub":"acr:123;type=STAT","updated_at":1509463516,"name":"User","email":"user@email.com"}
1`

---

## Try #2

If I do

```
$userInfo = json_encode($userInfo, true);
```

I got

`{"sub":"acr:123;type=STAT","updated_at":1509463516,"name":"User","email":"user@email.com"}
"true"`

---

How do I get rid of the `1` or `true` below it, and only get the JSON data?

Is there another param for `json_decode()` that I need to pass in?

Comment: The text is a true json https://3v4l.org/OdAvi . It seems as if you append the string with the true. Sure this is a copy paste of the code?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` curl option. `curl_exec` is just returning `true` without that, (it *echoes* the response and *returns* true; [see curl_exec return values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues)) and `json_decode(true)` is true.

> How would one go about and debug this further?

A couple of things to experiment with:

1. Remove `$userInfo = json_decode($userInfo, true);` and 
   `dd($userInfo);`. Without the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option set, you should still see the non-decoded JSON, but not the `true` or `1`.
2. Add another `dd($userInfo);` before the `json_decode`. You'll see what `curl_exec` actually returned, which may help you eliminate `json_decode` as a possible cause for this odd looking behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The following line should solve your problem with the response.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```